# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Transaction is not a known entity type

Tags: java, spring, jpa

When I try to persist an entity to the database, I get the error in the subject line. I have it in the persistence.xml along side my other classes, which happen to work and persist.

I know this question has been asked many times but each time it seems to have a different cause. I tried the suggestions elsewhere. If nothing else you can shed light on a mystery for me. I am pretty new to Java as well as anything Inversion of Control.

My Transaction is a valid class. Trust me when it works. It works in every sense- rendering the result of its' computation to the jsp page, even sending it to pubsub and unpacking it when it returns. It simply doesn't work when I try to persist it through a DAO (entity manager).

```java
@Entity
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    String uuid;
    @Transient
    Wallet senderWallet; // should this be transient? Can it be?
    @Column(name = "address")
    String recipientAddress;
    double amount;
    @Transient
    HashMap<String, Object> output; // like basic receipt
    @Transient
    HashMap<String, Object> input; // like wire transfer document
```

I made a lot of this transient just to exclude what could be wrong.

I strongly suspect it has something to do with higher level configuration and structure. I am new to Java and these types of frameworks in general but I would guess that we should be seeing a Transaction.class file in the bin folder, correct? You can see we do not.

[image]

Yet it's obviously being compiled and run, because I am building transactions all the time in my experimentation code. Something is funny about this, so if we can solve the persistence issue, great, but to learn something about what's going on in bin would be great. I am willing to do a refactor/overhaul of my structure and configuration if it requires it. In fact I am looking forward to it. I was told also I should be using beans like @service and @repository. I am using @Entity and @Controller. We were taught JDBC and then JPA first and second and then spring and making beans, but by that time I already started the project and my mind was still remembering and trying to digest the earlier stuff, so I have not made these types of beans. I might have some tight coupling in different places that I can fix but my first priority is getting Transaction persisting. Other entities persist no problem and the class itself works and I see nothing special about this one. I have tried various permutations but in particular, should I not see Transaction.class files?

I see all my class files for every single thing used in my Target folder. That's a maven folder that is sibling of src and bin, and seems to be used for making artifacts. Might I have been running my code through that and certain entities are invisible to spring but visible to eclipse/tomcat? If so how to correct? I am only guessing wildly

Edit:

Here is a class that is persisting fine:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    String username;
    String password;
    String hint;
    String answer;
    String email;
    @Embedded
    WalletForDB wallet;
```

Here's my persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Case Study">
        <class>privblock.gerald.ryan.entity.Transaction</class>
        <class>privblock.gerald.ryan.entity.Account</class>
        <class>privblock.gerald.ryan.entity.Block</class>
        <class>privblock.gerald.ryan.entity.Blockchain</class>
        <class>privblock.gerald.ryan.entity.User</class>
        <class>privblock.gerald.ryan.entity.WalletForDB</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- DB configuration -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blockchain" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                value="root" />

            <!-- EclipseLink configuration -->
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation"
                value="create-or-extend-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

BTW my configuration is now broken, as I tried to make my folder structure like Maven/Spring conforming and I cleaned and updated project. For some reason the combination of Tomcat, Spring, Maven and Eclipse is not working. I don't know which, I don't know if I'm close but that's a separate problem.

Comment: can you post your other class which is working fine as well as your persistence.xml?

Comment: posted, but as you can see I also broke my server. I can still test persistence though, inside a main method.